# how to access mysql in hadoop VM from host machine

Tags: mysql, hadoop, ambari

I'm tring to connect to mysqL via VM hadoop, I got this error:

```
# mysql -u root -p
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

I confirm that .jar is in the Java share directory:

```
# ls /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Execute the following command:

```
# ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql --jdbc-driver=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Setup ambari-server
Copying /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources
If you are updating existing jdbc driver jar for mysql with mysql-connector-java.jar. Please remove the old driver jar, from all hosts. Restarting services that need the driver, will automatically copy the new jar to the hosts.
JDBC driver was successfully initialized.
Ambari Server 'setup' completed successfully.
```

How I can't connect to mysql ?
Thank you

Comment: MySQL cli does not need MySQL-java-connector. It needs the cli application to be installed (well, copied) on the host you want to connect from.

Comment: ok, but I have postgresql is installed, I verified by runing this command line: sudo su postgres -c 'psql -l'.   How can I lunch it in VM hadoop, I tired excuting psql -l , I got:  psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "root", database "postgres", SSL off , I changed pg_hba.conf by adding " local   all       root           peer" but always I got the same message and I can't connect to postgres.

Comment: If you have a different question, then pls ask it in a new post.

Comment: I don't understand... Are you trying to connect to mysql or Postgres? You shouldn't be using both

Comment: Look man, simply try to check "systemctl status mysqld" / "systemctl status mariadb" and see the output.